# How to get the range of a non blank cell in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I´m trying to get the values of the rows that don't have a blank cell in column K.

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var bigrange = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet').getRange("K2:K").getValues();
//  var smallrange= bigrange .filter(String);

  for (var i=0; i < smallrange.length; i++) {

var calId = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet').getRange("M" + [i+ 2]).getValue();    

}
```

The code above works if I don't use the .filter(String). But since my data is big and most of range K2:K is blank, I think I should use the .filter(String).

What is the best way of getting the range of the few cells in K2:K that are not blank?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this answer?

### Pattern 1:

- The sheet name is `sheet`. In this sheet, you want to retrieve the ranges when the cell of column "K" is empty.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modified script, at first, the values are retrieved from "K2:K". Then, the ranges are retrieved from the values.

```
var sheetName = "sheet"; // Please set the sheet name here.

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var values = sheet.getRange("K2:K").getValues();
var ranges = values.map(function(e, i) {return e[0] ? sheetName + "!K" + (i + 2) : ""}).filter(String);
Logger.log(ranges)
```

### Pattern 2:

- The sheet name is `sheet`. In this sheet, you want to retrieve the values of the column "M" when the cell of column "K" is empty.

From your question and script, I also understood like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modified script, at first, the values are retrieved from "A2:M". Then, the values of the column "M" when the column "K" is empty are retrieved.

```
var sheetName = "sheet"; // Please set the sheet name here.

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var values = sheet.getRange("A2:M").getValues();
var res = values.map(function(e) {return e[10] ? e[12] : ""}).filter(String);
Logger.log(res)
```

### Note:

- In both modified scripts, from your script, it supposes that you want to retrieve the values from one sheet which is `sheet`.

### References:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.